# Is there an opensource or other asp.net javascript api to generate html elements for types of survey questions

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, frameworks, survey

I hope this question isn't confusing. But I need to generate HTML code to produce a survey form on the client-side (using javascript or as a last resort, ajax callbacks to server), then later stored server-side. The user must be able to add questions, by selecting the type of question first. Types are multiple choice (the user can then add as many choices as he wants) and numeric (with min and max parameters).

I have found a bunch of opensource asp.net forms controls that implement ajax callbacks to generate the HTML, but nothing for MVC3. I dont really want to implement both aspx pages in my MVC3 project, so forms components aren't feasible.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you need not to do ajax call backs, jquery can handle it for you very easily. This link can be useful for you:

http://www.bluelemoncode.com/post/2011/11/30/Adding-HTML-control-dynamically-using-jQuery.aspx

or if you search on google for "jquery add control dynamically", you will get a lot of good posts, later when you need to save you can do JQuery based call to a webservice and save your data.